# Flask/Python: Sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am new in Flask and I am trying to create a blog. I want to create a page from where I would like to insert the posts. In theory, the page should redirect to the index but every time I try to insert content in the page "add" I get an error. Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime




 
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/admin/Desktop/Blog_Project/blog2.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Blogpost(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(50))
    author = db.Column(db.String(20))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')
    

@app.route('/post')
def post():
    return render_template('post.html')


@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html')


@app.route('/prova')
def prova():
    return render_template('prova.html')


@app.route('/add')
def add():
    return render_template('add.html')

@app.route('/addpost', methods=['POST'])
def addpost():
    
    title = request.form['title']
    subtitle = request.form['subtitle']
    author = request.form["author"]
    content = request.form['content']


    
    post = Blogpost(title=title, subtitle=subtitle, author=author, content=content, date_posted = datetime.now())


    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
    

    return redirect(url_for('index'))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: blogpost
[SQL: INSERT INTO blogpost (title, subtitle, author, date_posted, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('ds', 'ds', 'sd', '2020-09-08 12:55:25.333277', 'ds')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

As far as I understand, the problem is that Flask cannot create the table blogpost in the database blog2 and fill it with the values that I inserted in the code. I have read some documentation in internet and in Stackoverflow and apparently some people fixed the same problem using the method `db.create_all()` but I am not sure where I should insert it or if I should reorganize the code in another way. Have you got any suggestion? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You should create the db first (I mean, add the tables to it)

Comment: You mean, create them manually? Should it not happen directly through the code?

Comment: In raw sqlalchemy, if you don't issue a `Base.metadata.create_all`, it won't do it automatically. I don't know much about the flask-sqlalchemy plugin, but except if stated the other way, you should indeed https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#create-a-schema

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Note that the `create_all` command does not keep track of changes. If you add columns to existing tables they will not appear. As you are new, solutions like [alembic](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/) are probably a bit too difficult to get right. Just be aware that it is a problem you need to solve for long-term projects. `alembic` is *one* solution.

Comment: I indeed solved the problem using a create_all command as global variable but it is good to know that I can´t do any changes to the tables structure. Thank you for your suggestion.